# Why does org-babel hang when piping to xsel?

Tags: org-babel

It doesn't hang if I open eshell;)

```
#+begin_src shell
echo "ehlo" |xsel -b
#+end_src
```

Comment: It does not hang for me, but it behaves better if I specify `-i`: in that case, it stores `ehlo` in the clipboard (although it works without the `-i` on the command line). I suspect that the stdin/stdout plumbing is different enough between babel and the shell to confuse `xsel`.